# NetSuite SuiteTalk REST Web Services - How to Request Financial Statement Reports

Tags: python, rest, api, netsuite, suitetalk

I'm attempting to obtain a profit and loss statement, or balance sheet, using REST Web Services within Netsuite.

I've been successful at calling unique ID records (customers, vendors, and their respective data), but now I'd like to be able to pull a set of financials for a specific period/entity. Is there a way I can do that using Python, Postman, or does REST Web Services not support that sort of functionality?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is not possible to request Reports in SuiteTalk REST WS, since Reports are quite old feature (you cannot even load them in SuiteScript as far as I know).

Comment: What strategy would you recommend to be able to programatically pull financial information from Netsuite's API? Which resource should I focus on to build balance sheet, profit and loss, or trial balance?

Comment: @trevoraaron I'm trying to do the same; what did you end up doing?

Comment: @lukas1994 right now this functionality isn't supported by Netsuite REST Web Services. I've been told it's logged as Netsuite Enhancement 168908 but can't actually see it myself since I'm not an admin (Netsuite is so frustrating sometimes...) There is a way you can use Netsutie Analytics to create a trial balance and REST Web Services will work to pull Analytics reports. Give it a shot, let me know how I can help